# Where is the p:fileUpload uploaded file saved and how do I change it?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, file-upload, glassfish, primefaces

I use the simple File upload of Primefaces in development with Netbeans. My test example is similar to to the Primefaces manual.
**My question: where does the file get uploaded on my local computer? How can I change the path for it? Thx!**

The jsf file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Page test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello! My first JSF generated page!
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload value="#{fileBean.file}" mode="simple" />
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

and the managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;


    @ManagedBean

@RequestScoped
public class FileBean {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public FileBean() {
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's by default saved in either the servlet container's memory or the temp folder, depending on the file size and the Apache Commons FileUpload configuration (see also "Filter Configuration" section of the `<p:fileUpload>` chapter in [PrimeFaces User's Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html)).

You shouldn't worry about this at all. The servlet container and PrimeFaces know exactly what they do. You should in the command button's action method actually be saving the uploaded file contents to the location where ***you*** need it to be. You can get the uploaded file contents as an `InputStream` by `UploadedFile#getInputStream()` or as a `byte[]` by `UploadedFile#getContents()` (getting a `byte[]` is potentially memory expensive in case of large files, you know, each `byte` eats one byte of JVM's memory, so don't do that in case of large files).

E.g.

```html
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{fileBean.save}" ajax="false"/>
```

with

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void save() throws IOException {
    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getFileName());
    InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/uploads", filename));

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    }
}
```

*(`FilenameUtils` and `IOUtils` are from Commons IO which you should anyway already have installed in order to get `<p:fileUpload>` to work)*

To generate unique file names, you may find [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) facility helpful.

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getFileName());
String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filename) + "_";
String extension = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);
File file = File.createTempFile(basename, extension, "/path/to/uploads");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! I got the logic of it and it just worked.

Comment: Can not set static paths like : "/path/to/uploads".. How to find dynamic path for primefaces uploaded file.

Comment: Then you'll perhaps need to save it in DB. This is indeed a bad practice, but that's the only solution when you cannot set static paths.

Answer (score 0):

I used simple mode, GlassFish 4.0 and PrimeFaces 4.0

Backing Bean

```
private UploadedFile file;
private String destination="C:\\temp\\";

public void upload() {

    System.out.println("uploading");
    if(file != null) {  
        System.out.println("the file is" +file);
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful" + file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  

        try {
           copyFile(file.getFileName(), file.getInputstream());
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    System.out.println("uploaf finished");
}  

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    try {
        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
             out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("New file created!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

JSF page

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{staffController.upload}"/>
```